# Popovers in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uipopovercontroller

I would like to display popovers with `UITableView`'s as content (this works) on some button presses and then get the selected item as string as buttontitle or some textview text. I've found a few example on how to do this with protocols but still get an error.
My code:

In popoverViewController.h

```
@protocol popoverViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)getRowText:(NSString *)string;
@end
```

I declare an id delegate2 variable and set its property to:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<popoverViewControllerDelegate> delegate2;
```

In the popoverViewController.m file I synthesize the variable, and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method I have this, and this line seems to cause the error I`m having:

```
[self.delegate2 getRowText:[someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

In mainViewController.m I add the popoverViewControllerDelegate to the ViewControllers protocol and have its header file imported. And then have some code in the `-(void)getRowText:` method which doesnt get called.

`UIPopovers` and such are set up as they work as needed, problem arises when I press a row in the tableview. I get the

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[UIPopoverViewController
>   getRowText:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x57ca80'

Could anyone give some advice with this?

Comment: Where are you setting delegate2 and to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the error and cant believe how silly I/it was.

I had a viewController.delegate2 = self.   line with period instead of a semicolon, I wonder why it compiled tho.